How to wait Subscribe to finish and return value from function?
I have a below service
export class DataService {
  private jsonFormData$: BehaviorSubject<FormData>;
  private jsonPath: string;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getJsonFormData(): Observable<FormData> {
    if (!this.jsonFormData$) {
      this.loadJsonFormData();
    }
    return this.jsonFormData$.asObservable();
  }

  private loadJsonFormData() {
    this.http.get(this.jsonPath).subscribe((formData: any) => {
      this.jsonFormData$.next(formData);
    });
  }
}

and i call this from a component as below
this.dataSvc.getJsonFormData().subscribe((formData: any) => {
      this.jsonFormData = formData;
      console.log('const', this.jsonFormData);
    });

however, it always undefined as observable from service
return this.jsonFormData$.asObservable();

How do i want for the observable to load and then return the value.
Modified code works. But first time it returns null from component
getJsonFormData(): Observable<FormData> {
    if (!this.jsonFormData$) {
      this.jsonFormData$ = new BehaviorSubject<FormData>(null!);
      this.loadJsonFormData();
    }
    return this.jsonFormData$.asObservable();
  }



Change the loadJsonFormData method to return observable.

In getJsonFormData, you should check whether the observable contains value with this.jsonFormData$.getValue(). If not, then you should return the observable from the loadJsonFormData method.


getJsonFormData(): Observable<FormData> {
  if (!this.jsonFormData$.getValue()) {
    return this.loadJsonFormData();
  }

  return this.jsonFormData$.asObservable();
}

private loadJsonFormData() {
  let ob$ = this.http.get(this.jsonPath);

  return ob$.pipe(
    tap((formData: any) => {
      this.jsonFormData$.next(formData);
    })
  );
}

As you call the observable with this.dataSvc.getJsonFormData().subscribe(...), this will fire the observable from the loadJsonFormData for the first time.
Demo @ StackBlitz

Initalize your BehaviorSubject first then check if it doesn't have value then call api.
for ex.
export class DataService {
  private jsonFormData$: BehaviorSubject<FormData> = new BehaviorSubject(null);
  private jsonPath: string;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getJsonFormData(): Observable<FormData> {
    if (!this.jsonFormData$.getValue()) {
      this.loadJsonFormData();
    }
    return this.jsonFormData$.asObservable();
  }

  private loadJsonFormData() {
    this.http.get(this.jsonPath).subscribe((formData: any) => {
      this.jsonFormData$.next(formData);
    });
  }
}


Thank you. It says Type 'BehaviorSubject' is not assignable to type 'BehaviorSubject'.

try new BehaviorSubject(null as FormData)

didnt work Conversion of type 'null' to type 'FormData' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.

try this null as unknown as FormData

I have modified the code and posted in the original question and it works, but first time the function still returns null from component

yes first time it will always send null because behaviour subject is preserving your old value and it will send.
If you don't want to preserve value then use Subject instead of behaviour subject
